# Software IMSI and Software Simcards with gpg expiry?

Tags: linux

Software IMSI

Why can IMSI not be a software IMSI, such that it would help anonymizing
in cells. I got in one cell with IMSI generated A, in other cell with IMSI
generated B.

Software Simcards simplified, but as ISOs

When using UMTS, why can't we build a simplified phone using cryptographic blobs, that can be paid.

There was an older discussion about Simcards being an own computer, but
what, if I just want to phone, and not mess with flatrates or plastic?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

GSMA published Embedded SIM Specification and it has been already implemented by device manufacturers on several models. This standard defines remote provisioning of machine to machine (M2M) and mobile consumer devices by taking “over the air” concept much further. Now OTA can perform initial MNO subscription and change subscription from one MNO to another through eSIM profile provisioning flow,  Refer to the SGP.22 for the details

1. Profile Preparation
   When user is ready to subscribe to the operator's service, the MNO prepares a profile in the SM-DP+ . MNO and SM-DP+ shares a code that identifies the generated profile in the SM-DP+. The operator provides the code and the SM-DP+ address to the user
2. Profile download
   The user launches the LPA in the device, and inputs the code and the SM-DP+ address. The LPA contacts the SM-DP+ and augments the eUICC to establish a secure channel to the SM-DP+. If the eUICC and SM-DP+ successfully completes mutual authentication, then the LPA downloads a profile package from the SM-DP+.
3. Profile installation and report
   The LPA delivers the profile package’ to the eUICC. The eUICC unpacks and installs the profile, and returns the installation result, i.e., success or failure, to the LPA. The LPA relays the profile installation result to the SM-DP+, and eventually to the MNO. If the profile is successfully installed, then the MNO can provide communication service to the user.